# Как отправить файл по http из консольного приложения на C#?

Tags: c#, fileupload

Нужно отправить файл из консольного приложения на C# на веб сервер и потом принять данные.  Смотрю примеры, но не работает. Как организовать отправку фала?

Я делаю так

```
            string uri = "http://mysite/api/postfile";
            string localPath = @"c:\path_to_file.doc";
            var parameters = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "parametr1", "parametr1_Value" }
            };

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                client.QueryString = parameters;
                var responseBytes = client.UploadFile(uri, localPath);
                var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
                Console.WriteLine("\n Ответ \n {0}", response);
            }
```

На сервере принимает контроллер

```
public class PostFileController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
        {
            if (upload != null)
        {
            // получаем имя файла
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
            // сохраняем файл в папку Files в проекте
            upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));
            return Content("1");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("0");
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Какой сервер, какие примеры, что не работает? Приведите свой код.

Comment: @Zufir Сервер Asp Net MVC, приложение обычное на C#. Отправлять файл либо формой либо байтами- не важно. Но что-то не отправляет. Я пытался через WebClient на приложении отправить

Comment: Разве что HTTP Post, если сервер поддерживает.

Comment: @VladD ,да- я в контроллере над экшеном прописал  [HttpPost] . В ответ я получаю данные из контроллера, но проблема, что я файл не могу отослать, что б вторым шагом его принять

Comment: Подождите, то есть в `[HttpPost]`-метод данные приходят? Что вы имеете в виду под «вторым шагом»?

Comment: @VladD я просто в контроллере отсылаю в респонс "1" и в приложении вижу, что сервер ответил.Я файл через WebClient не могу отослать.

Comment: @VladD , я делаю, как здесь https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RakzinRoman: Ничего не понятно. У вас проблема на клиенте или на сервере? Опишите точно, что вы делаете и что происходит.

Comment: @VladD Нужно взять файл "file.txt" на клиенте(c#) и передать его на сервер на путь "site.com/api/fileupload" (сервер C# Asp Net MVC приложение). Потом прочитать файл и записать на сервере в папку "C:\Files\". Как реализовать передачу, любым методом, что б он работал)) ?

Comment: @RakzinRoman способ которым вы отправляете файл предназначен для ftp серверов, а судя по всему сервер у вас http и не предназначен для подобной работы, единственный способ который я вижу это отправка байтами

Comment: @Buka ок. Как реализовать это через http на клиенте и на сервере?

Comment: @VladD Я откорректировал вопрос- то, как я делаю. Я видел Ваши ответы в сети, но что-то не могу подключить.Обычное действие, а не могу отослать файл...странно

Comment: @VladD, вопрос должен звучать так: есть некий сервер, на который из браузера через форму можно загружать файл. Как на C# написать отправку файла так, чтобы сервер сервер её корректно обработал.

Comment: @Qwertiy: О, теперь понял, спасибо.

Comment: @VladD да.Только я везде примеры нахожу для браузера, а мне надо с консольного приложения отправить(ну либо WPF приложения-не важно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(localPath))
{
    HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

    var filename = Path.GetFileName(localPath);

    // эмулируем <input type="file" name="upload"/>
    formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "upload");

    // эмулируем (action="{url}" method="post")
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);

    // и т. д.
}
```

Одолжено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925159/276994).

---

Если вам очень-очень не хочется асинхронный код, можно сделать и блокирующий вызов (но я бы не рекомендовал):

```
    var response = client.PostAsync(url, formData).Result;
```

Comment: я сэмулировал вставку файла в форму, а теперь не принимает. ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase upload) upload пустой в режиме отладки. Как можно принять файл?

Comment: я принимаю, как здесь написано http://metanit.com/sharp/articles/26.php

Comment: О! Не знал, что есть такой класс :)

Comment: @RakzinRoman, проверь `name`. И вообще, по шагам из моего ответа посмотри. И ещё `Expect100Continue` выключи.

Comment: @VladD, `await` не забыл? UPDATE: А, не, там `Result`. Ну не надо же так делать?!

Comment: @Qwertiy а как name проверить?

Comment: @VladD вот например ещё пример, как принимать, но у меня пустой HttpPostedFileBase upload     . www.cyberforum.ru/asp-net-mvc/thread1075531.html

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47474/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-rakzin-roman).

Comment: По результатам обсуждения в чате: дополнительная проблема была вызвана несоответствием имён. После замены `"file"` на `"upload"` всё взлетело как надо.

Answer (score 2):

Файл передаётся в кодировке [`multipart/form-data`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data). Соответственно надо:

1. Сгенерировать разлелитель (например, `Asrf456BGe4h`)
2. Отправить заголовок

   ```
   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Asrf456BGe4h
   ```
3. отправить **тело** запроса:

   ```
   (отсутствующая преамбула)
   --Asrf456BGe4h
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AttachedFile1"; filename="horror-photo-1.jpg"
   Content-Type: image/jpeg
   (пустая строка)
   (двоичное содержимое первой фотографии)
   --Asrf456BGe4h--
   (отсутствующий эпилог - пустая строка)
   ```

   Обращаю внимание на два дефиса в конце.

> А то над просто вещью вроде бы ломаю голову несколько часов

1. Устанавливаешь [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
2. Отправляешь файл через браузер, откуда всё работает.
3. Смотришь в фиддлере, что именно отправилось.
4. Отправляешь своим кодом. Смотришь в фиддлере, что отправилось.
5. Допиливаешь свой код, пока отправляемое на шаге 4 не совпадёт с тем, что было на 3.

Comment: а можно по проще? Мне нужно один файл за раз передавать. Лиж бы оно работало. Ато над просто вещью вроде бы ломаю голову несколько часов

Comment: @RakzinRoman, нельзя проще. Либо переделывай сервер, чтобы он принимал `Stream` (в WCF так можно было, про webapi не в курсе) и шли как написано в соседнем ответе.

Comment: @RakzinRoman, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется так:
Записываете файл в поток:

```
var file = File.ReadAllBytes(filename); 
var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url); //url - адрес сервера
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
//Отправляете на сервер(думаю знаете как)
```

action, который принимает поток байтов должен иметь аргумент byte[]
Как записать поток байтов в файл описано здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397235/write-bytes-to-file

Comment: Вопрос был, как передать файл на обычный сервер. Это вообще не ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В свое время написал статью [.Net в 1С. Асинхронные HTTP запросы, отправка Post нескольких файлов multipart/form-data, сжатие трафика с использованием gzip, deflate, удобный парсинг сайтов и т.д.](http://infostart.ru/public/466052/)

Правда там пример на 1С но это не особо важно

```
     public async Task  SendPostFile(string urlserviceapiSent)
    {
        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        using (var content = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(urlserviceapiSent);
            var values = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String>()
                               {
                                   { "Name", "name"},
                                   { "id", "id"}
                                };

            //      content.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
            foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
            {
                content.Add(new System.Net.Http.StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
            }

            string fileName = @"C:/ТестXML";
            var fileContent = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName)
            };
            content.Add(fileContent);

            // Вариант отправки двоичных данных из файла но более краткий
            var fileContent2 = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName));
            content.Add(fileContent2, "attachment", "TestXml");



            var stringContent = new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Тестовая строка"));
            stringContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Строка"
            };
            content.Add(stringContent);

            var requestUri = "api/values/SendFiles";

            var result = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
            var str = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            textBox.AppendText(str + Environment.NewLine);

        }
    }
```

Выдает такой

> // Вот как выглядит отправляемый запрос                 //POST
>   http://localhost:40320/api/values/SendFiles HTTP/1.1 //Content-Type:
>   multipart/form-data; boundary="9f2d525a-7383-46ab-8fc7-419d73486c02"
>   //Host: localhost:40320 //Content-Length: 811 //Expect: 100-continue
>   //Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> //--9f2d525a-7383-46ab-8fc7-419d73486c02 //Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=utf-8 //Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Name
>
> //name //--9f2d525a-7383-46ab-8fc7-419d73486c02 //Content-Type:
>   text/plain; charset=utf-8 //Content-Disposition: form-data; name=id
>
> //id //--9f2d525a-7383-46ab-8fc7-419d73486c02 //Content-Disposition:
>   form-data; filename="=?utf-8?B?0J/RgNC+0YHRgtC+0KHRgtGA0L7QutCw?=";
>   name=attachment //Content-Type: text/plain
>
> //Тестовая строка //--9f2d525a-7383-46ab-8fc7-419d73486c02
>   //Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   filename="=?utf-8?B?0KLQtdGB0YJYTUw=?=" //Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream
>
> //12345 //--9f2d525a-7383-46ab-8fc7-419d73486c02
>   //Content-Disposition: form-data; name=attachment; filename=TestXml;
>   filename*=utf-8''TestXml
>
> //12345 //--9f2d525a-7383-46ab-8fc7-419d73486c02--

Там же есть ссылка на сервис http://pastebin.com/1kyhAdai

```
[NonAction]
        string fileName(MultipartFileData fileData)
        {
            string fileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                return "";
            }

            if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
            {
                fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
            }
            if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
            {
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            }

            return fileName;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendFiles()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Holds the response body

                // Read the form data and return an async task.
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                // This illustrates how to get the form data.
                foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
                {
                    foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                    {
                        sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", key, val));
                    }
                }

                // This illustrates how to get the file names for uploaded files.
                foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
                    sb.Append(string.Format("Uploaded file: {0} {1} ({2} bytes)\n", fileName(file), fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length));
                }
                return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString())
                };
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
            }


        }
```