# Отправка файлов с помощью C#

Tags: php, c#

Как отправить файл с использованием C# на сервер, на котором находится php-файл обработчик через POST запрос? Простейший пример, который работает.

Comment: Через FormUrlEncodedContent, посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/895562/213987) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583073/213987) про c# часть и [что-нибудь типа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590588/213987) про php-часть

Answer (score 1):

Установи NuGet пакет Microsoft.Net.Http.

```
private async Task<System.IO.Stream> Upload(string actionUrl, string paramString, Stream paramFileStream, byte [] paramFileBytes)
{
    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(paramString);
    HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(paramFileStream);
    HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(paramFileBytes);
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(stringContent, "param1", "param1");
        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file1", "file1");
        formData.Add(bytesContent, "file2", "file2");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(actionUrl, formData);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваши параметры в fileStreamContent и bytesContent, в чем различия?